# "error: 'A' cannot be overloaded", but there isn't any overload in the code

Tags: c++, arduino, overloading

I've just got an Arduino and started learning C++. I decided to start by implementing a simple "car dodge" game, present in those [very old "9999 in 1" handhelds](http://i00.i.aliimg.com/img/pb/664/155/550/550155664_261.jpg) using a LCD and pushbuttons. However I encountered a very strange issue with the code.

The compiler believes I'm trying to override `setUp` and `tearDown`, but I can't see where this is happening. There is literally no further instances than the original function definitions, yet this is what happens when I try to compile (using Stino for Sublime Text, if that's relevant):

```
Compiling lcd...
Creating C:\Users\Leonardo\Documents\Arduino_Build\lcd\lcd.ino.cpp.o...
C:\Users\Leonardo\Documents\Arduino_Build\lcd\lcd.ino.cpp:31: error: 'virtual void Scene::setUp(LiquidCrystal)' cannot be overloaded
C:\Users\Leonardo\Documents\Arduino_Build\lcd\lcd.ino.cpp:25: error: with 'virtual void Scene::setUp(LiquidCrystal)'
C:\Users\Leonardo\Documents\Arduino_Build\lcd\lcd.ino.cpp:32: error: 'virtual void Scene::tearDown(LiquidCrystal)' cannot be overloaded
C:\Users\Leonardo\Documents\Arduino_Build\lcd\lcd.ino.cpp:26: error: with 'virtual void Scene::tearDown(LiquidCrystal)'
[Stino - Error 1]
```

This is the "game" source file, `lcd.ino`, which has nothing of game yet:

```
#include "LiquidCrystal.h"

#define LEFT_BUTTON_PIN 8
#define RIGHT_BUTTON_PIN 7

#define LEFT_PRESSED B10
#define RIGHT_PRESSED B01

#define STATE_SPLASH 0
#define STATE_PLAY 1
#define STATE_SCORE 2

// LiquidCrystal display with:
// rs on pin 12
// rw on pin 11
// enable on pin 10
// d4, d5, d6, d7 on pins 5, 4, 3, 2
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 10, 5, 4, 3, 2);


class Scene {
    public:
    virtual void loop(byte input, LiquidCrystal lcd) {}
    virtual void setUp(LiquidCrystal lcd) {}
    virtual void tearDown(LiquidCrystal lcd) {}
};

class Splash : public Scene {
    public: void loop(byte input, LiquidCrystal lcd) {
        lcd.print("Welcome to CAR DODGE");
        lcd.print("Press LEFT to start!");
    }
};

class Game : public Scene {
    public: void loop(byte input, LiquidCrystal lcd) {
        lcd.print("HI");
    }
};

class Score : public Scene {
    public: void loop(byte input, LiquidCrystal lcd) {
        lcd.print("HI");
    }
};


byte currentMode = STATE_SPLASH;
Scene *gameModes[] = {new Splash(), new Game(), new Score()};

byte getInput() {
    bool leftSample1 = digitalRead(LEFT_BUTTON_PIN);
    bool rightSample1 = digitalRead(RIGHT_BUTTON_PIN);
    Serial.print(leftSample1);
    Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.println(rightSample1);
}

void changeGameMode(byte next) {
    gameModes[currentMode]->tearDown(lcd);
    gameModes[next]->setUp(lcd);
    currentMode = next;
}

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);

    pinMode(LEFT_BUTTON_PIN, INPUT);
    pinMode(RIGHT_BUTTON_PIN, INPUT);
    lcd.begin(20, 4);

    changeGameMode(STATE_SPLASH);
}

void loop() {
    byte input = getInput();
    gameModes[currentMode]->loop(input, lcd);
    delay(150);
}
```

**EDIT:** lcd.ino.cpp contents, which is generated by the Arduino build tools:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "LiquidCrystal.h"

#define LEFT_BUTTON_PIN 8
#define RIGHT_BUTTON_PIN 7

#define LEFT_PRESSED B10
#define RIGHT_PRESSED B01

#define STATE_SPLASH 0
#define STATE_PLAY 1
#define STATE_SCORE 2

// LiquidCrystal display with:
// rs on pin 12
// rw on pin 11
// enable on pin 10
// d4, d5, d6, d7 on pins 5, 4, 3, 2
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 10, 5, 4, 3, 2);


class Scene {
    public:

virtual void setUp(LiquidCrystal lcd);
virtual void tearDown(LiquidCrystal lcd);
byte getInput();
void changeGameMode(byte next);

virtual void loop(byte input, LiquidCrystal lcd) {}
    virtual void setUp(LiquidCrystal lcd) {}
    virtual void tearDown(LiquidCrystal lcd) {}
};

class Splash : public Scene {
    public: void loop(byte input, LiquidCrystal lcd) {
        lcd.print("Welcome to CAR DODGE");
        lcd.print("Press LEFT to start!");
    }
};

class Game : public Scene {
    public: void loop(byte input, LiquidCrystal lcd) {
        lcd.print("HI");
    }
};

class Score : public Scene {
    public: void loop(byte input, LiquidCrystal lcd) {
        lcd.print("HI");
    }
};


byte currentMode = STATE_SPLASH;
Scene *gameModes[] = {new Splash(), new Game(), new Score()};

byte getInput() {
    bool leftSample1 = digitalRead(LEFT_BUTTON_PIN);
    bool rightSample1 = digitalRead(RIGHT_BUTTON_PIN);
    Serial.print(leftSample1);
    Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.println(rightSample1);
}

void changeGameMode(byte next) {
    gameModes[currentMode]->tearDown(lcd);
    gameModes[next]->setUp(lcd);
    currentMode = next;
}

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);

    pinMode(LEFT_BUTTON_PIN, INPUT);
    pinMode(RIGHT_BUTTON_PIN, INPUT);
    lcd.begin(20, 4);

    changeGameMode(STATE_SPLASH);
}

void loop() {
    byte input = getInput();
    gameModes[currentMode]->loop(input, lcd);
    delay(150);
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Is this the complete source file `lcd.ino.cpp`?

Comment: Can you please point out which of the lines in the shown code that is lines 25, 26, 31 and 32?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I don't know either, the line numbers seem to be off in the full code too. I'll post the whole file. EDIT: now the question contains the whole file, but the line numbers don't make sense at all.

Comment: Is is possible you are looking at the wrong file, or you did not save the file to disk?

Comment: @Wimmel This is the only file in the project, and it is up-to-date in the disk.

Comment: The line numbers doesn't really match up with the source still. Have you edited the source since you got the errors? Have you tried to build again?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Exactly, this is the most up-to-date information: All files are saved, latest build (just re-ran it and it's the same as posted).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Now that you mentioned it, I realized that's the cpp file generated by the Arduino building process, not the actual source. I'll edit the question with the full (builder-processed) code.

Comment: There seems to be something odd about the generation of the C++ file. In the generated C++ file (`lcd.ino.cpp`) the `Scene` class contains function declarations for two of the functions *and* two of the global functions, plus the definitions you made in the `lcd.ino` file. I don't know much about the Arduino environment, but you could try to remove the `lcd.ino.cpp` file and try to build again.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Removed the whole Arduino_Build folder, rebuilt with no success. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer might be a little late but;

It appears the Arduino IDE doesn't like member functions being declared in the class definition.

Just to be clear:

```
class example {
    public:
           void function(){ /*code not here*/ };  
    private:
            int variable;
};

void example::function(){
    //code here
}
```

Comment: Indeed that was the issue! Maybe it's late for me, but I'm sure someone will benefit from this answer!

Answer (score 0):

From the MS C++ help:

> Virtual functions in a base class must be defined unless they are declared using the pure-specifier.

I think the null definition in the base class MAY be the problem. Either make the base class declaration pure, and delete the null definition, or provide a diagnostic non-null definition.

Comment: But they *are* defined. Even if the body of the member function is empty, it's still means the member function will be defined.

Comment: @joachim That's what I would expect. However I can't see any other problem, so it's worth checking if it's a compiler quirk/difference from MS. The error being presented relates to the intermediate file having declarations followed by definitions -- it seems to think the definition is an overload. But why?

Comment: Well the Arduino hardly uses the Microsoft C++ compiler.

Comment: The functions are defined, so I don't think that's the issue. It might be related to how the Arduino build transforms the code, see edit.

Answer (score 0):

In my particular case, the error occurred because I accidentally declared the same functions more than once.
Once I removed the extra function declarations, the issue was cleared.

Comment: Since your answer doesn't contain code or details, a comment would be more appropriate.